# Printing a square - can't find the error

Tags: java

The work I am currently doing requires me to 'draw' a square by printing '*' as the outline and '.' to fill it in. My code seems to work but it still isn't accepting it. I am a beginner, thanks.

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int square = 5;
        int line = 1;
        int stars = 1;
        int startLine = square / square;

        while (line <= startLine) {

            while (stars <= square) { // first line prints out dots for the value of square, in this case 5
                System.out.print("*");
                stars = stars + 1;
            }

            System.out.println();
            line = line + 1;                //prints new line and adds 1 to line. Meaning it will move to the next section as it is now greater than startLine
        }

        stars = 1;              //resets stars

        while (line <= square - 1) {// line will keep looping until its value is greater than square - 1

            while (stars <= startLine) {
                System.out.print("*");         // First character to print is *
                stars = stars + 1;
            }

            while (stars <= square - 1) {
                System.out.print(".");          //prints 3 dots
                stars = stars + 1;
            }

            while (stars <= square) {
                System.out.print("*");         // stars is equal to square so 1 star is printed 
                stars = stars + 1;
            }

            stars = 1;
            System.out.println();
            line = line + 1;              // adds a value and loops around again
        }

        stars = 1;
        while (line <= square) {

            while (stars <= square) {
                System.out.print("*");
                stars = stars + 1;
            }

            System.out.println();
            line = line + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to make up the square and if I change the value of 'square' the size changes too. I can't see the problem.

Comment: Step 1: Format your code readably. *edit*: Looks like assylias did it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Your code seems to work as you expect. What is your problem?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing in it? It is working..?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways in doing this then having a loop for each line. one thing you can think about is you know it's a square so its always something like 5x5 in your case or 6x6, 7x7 etc...

lets say x for width and y for height of the square. You'll only need stars when your indexes are `*x5`, `5x*`, `1x*` and `*x1` anything else are "`.`"

so here's some pseudo-code

```
get width or height from user then set either the height or the width to the same thing that way its a square

for loop 1 to 5 //x - width
    for loop 1 to 5 //y - height
        if (check for *x5, 5x*, 1x* and *x1) //you can make a couple IF's if you want
            print a star
        else 
            print a dot
        end if
     print new line ("\n")
    next
next
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Which programming construct are you using? It's about Java.

Comment: pseudo-code is used. I wasn't gonna do the problem for him, because I think its homework, but simply point in him the right direction, for loops and if statements in java are very similar to the code I wrote.